# Undefined variable in view on server

Tags: php, laravel, deployment

My Laravel webpage works perfectly fine locally, but when I upload it to my server it breaks. It was working fine until the last update I made, where I added more or less the entire webpage.

There are some version mismatches between the two installations:

Local: Arch Linux
Server: Ubuntu 14.04
Local: php 5.6.16
Server: php 5.5.9

Here is a screenshot of the error I am currently facing, but there are more. If I comment this line another error shows:
[image: Error]
The failing view is a bar which is shown on all pages except the login page. "layouts/topbar.blade.php":

```html
<div class="container topbar-container" style="text-align:right;">
    <a class="btn btn-primary active" role="button" href= {{URL::to('/dashboard')}}>Dashboard</a>
    @if ($role == "admin")
        <a class="btn btn-primary active" role="button" href= {{URL::to('/dashboard/admin_settings')}}>Admin Settings</a>
    @endif
    <a class="btn btn-primary active" role="button" href= {{URL::to('/dashboard/settings')}}>Settings</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary active" role="button" href="{{ URL::to('/auth/logout') }}">Sign Out</a>
</div>
```

The view is included in the "layouts/master.blade.php" file:

```html
@if(!Request::is('auth/login'))
    <!! sidebar not included on login page. >
    @include('layouts.topbar')
@endif
```

Using this View Composer "ViewComposers/UserComposer.php":

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Auth;

class UserComposer
{
    /**
     * Create a new profile composer.
     *
     * @param  UserRepository  $users
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Bind data to the view.
     *
     * @param  View  $view
     * @return void
     */
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('role', Auth::user()->role);
    }
}
```

I am happy to provide more information if necessary, but I don't know what is relevant to be honest.

Comment: While this error occurs, is the user logged in or not? if not then Auth::user()->role will not be valid

Comment: The user is not logged in, but the view is not rendered when a user is not logged in. If I logout locally, it still works fine.

Comment: ah you mean that the View is only accesible if the user logged in , if not a middleware will redirect the user right? and you are using laravel 5 ?

Comment: There is only 1 screen where the user is not logged in and this view is not included in that case. Yes I am using Laravel 5. And yes, the user is redirected if it is not logged in.

Comment: Im sorry but i couldnt understand what you mean , You said in the above comment that a user is not logged in right? (then it wont work) try to login and access the same view and check if the error still occurs

Comment: In the specific case where this view is used, the user IS logged in. Always. I will add a snippet to the question that shows this.

Comment: check my answer , it works for me (i created a test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright just do this , its easy so lets do it from scratch

in your root directory open your terminal and type

```
php artisan make:provider ViewcomposerProvider
```

then navigate and open `app\providers\ViewcomposerProvider.php`

add this code to that file

```
    namespace App\Providers;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class Viewcomposer extends ServiceProvider {
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot() {
        view()->composer(['layouts.topbar'], function ($view) {

            if (Auth::check()) {
                $view->with('role', Auth::user()->role);
            } else {
                abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register() {
        //
    }
}
```

Then just go to `config\app.php`

and add this to the providers array

```
    App\Providers\ViewcomposerProvider::class,
```

This should work fine (tested on Ubuntu env)

**EDIT**

change the way you include topbar like this

```
     @if(!Request::is('auth/login') && Auth::check())
       @include('layouts.topbar')
     @endif
```

**EDIT 2**
Try this in your topbar (in this case i think there is no need for Viewcomposer but it should fix the issue)

```
   @if (Auth::user()->role == "admin")
        <a class="btn btn-primary active" role="button" href= {{URL::to('/dashboard/admin_settings')}}>Admin Settings</a>
    @endif
```

Comment: This is more or less the same I already had. I tried it anyway with the same result.

Comment: hmm it works for me , anyway what did you change exactly?

Comment: It does for me too, locally that is. As soon as I upload it to my server it breaks. If you mean what I changed since it worked - then I added this.

Comment: That broke the bar. That check I have works fine. The bar does not show on the login page, but it does show on all other pages.

Comment: yes this is wierd your check works fine(i just added something to it but i dont think its the issue, check edit), i have everything working in my pc right now,

Comment: Yes, that is what is so weird about this issue. Everything works perfectly fine on my laptop as well...

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I think I figured where the problem is. If I add a dd("test"); in my ViewComposerProvider.php nothing happens on the server, but it does locally. So it seems like my ViewComposerProvider.php does not work on the server. I checked the app.php and it is mentioned there just as on the local version.

Comment: Check my second update, i think its simpler without a View composer for this case (its the same) + can you please share your app.php providers array?

Comment: It does work yes. But why does my View Composer not work on the server but it does locally? This is really strange.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114988/discussion-between-achraf-khouadja-and-peter).

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the role `isset` first.

```
@if(isset($role) && $role == "admin")
```

Comment: This would 'fix' this problem, but the fact is that the role never exists, giving me a new problem.

Comment: @Peter Okay. Either remake the question and introduce the code that shows us how the Role is created/attached, and the model relationships, and I'll respond to do that, or mark this as the correct answer, and make a new question and I'll respond to that one. SO's not good for long drawn out answers with several layers of problems. The **direct** issue here is that you're not checking if variables are set, the **underlying** issue here is that  relationship is never accessible. Two different issues.

Comment: The underlying issue here is, that this code works perfectly fine on one machine, but not on my server. This does NOT fix the actual issue described.

Comment: @Peter That might be because your server cares about undefined index warnings, but your other machine (for some reason) has set the error reporting level to ignore undefined index warnings, which is another topic completely. It could also be due to a faulty migration, a difference in the database engine...a  whole host of other things.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful information. I will check up on this. I am quite certain it is not a database issue, as the database looks good and worked before I made these changes.

Comment: Can you check what the `error_reporting` is set to? It's possible your other server swallows those warnings too, or puts them in `Log::info`, it all depends on how the production setup is configured. Alternatively, can you tell us what the model relationship looks like? Which package are you using for your Role management? Is it baked into Laravel's ACL?

Comment: error_reporting is set to -1. The role I added is just another string I added to the user.